# How to write a script that reads a file and counts the number of intgers after an "=" sign

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a script that reads a file that has multiple values similar to the below i.e log extract

1=232=343=5610=66=???????
1=332=343=2010=46=????????
1=392=343=3610=36=????????
1=132=343=9610=16=???????

Where the value 6=??????? or ???????? (could be any 7/8 byte integer or a 7/8 character).

I want to read/check the log that and prints any field with "6"=

Then check the length of this value, if it is greater than 8 integer/bytes

Then write the lines that have this value to a new file"

Comment: "Check the length of this value", and then what?

Comment: "check the length of this value and print the line that has this value to a new file" if it is less than 8 integer/bytes

Comment: Aha, that is not yet in the question :)

Comment: yes sorry I am new to this and just wanted to understand what to do.

Comment: Is any language excluded?

Comment: This is UNIX bash

Comment: Have attempted to clarify your question with edit, please check/ edit appropriately, if I have obscured your original meaning.

Comment: Meaning no python? @DjOlu not really stuff for bash.

Comment: `awk -F= '$1 == "6" { print length($2) }'`?

Comment: @XTian not sure if all values should be on new lines, looking at the commas.

Comment: I accepted the edit but yes that what I was after thanks.

Comment: @Jacob Vijm , I had noticed, but there's not a comma after every value. DjOlu please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/349765/edit) your question, and tidy it up, we are getting confused.

Comment: @XTian yeah, you are right, that's why I got the idea some where on the same line, some not. The q is still a bit foggy though :).

Answer (score 0):

For lines that start with `6=` followed by no more than 7 decimal digits (would match on `6=`, `6=123` or `6=123X45678` but not `6=12345678`):

```
grep -E '^6=[0-9]{0,7}([^0-9]|$)' < in > out
```

For lines that start with `6=` followed by no more than  7 characters:

```
grep -xE '6=.{0,7}' < in > out
```

For lines that start with `6=` followed by no more than  7 bytes:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -xE '6=.{0,7}' < in > out
```